# Clarification of pullback notation $F^\ast x$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I'm a little confused by this notation:

> *Solution*. The sphere $S^2$ has a parametrization by spherical coordinates (Figure 23.3(b)): $$F(\varphi,\theta)=(\sin\varphi\cos\theta,\sin\varphi\sin\theta,\cos\varphi)$$ on $D=\{(\varphi,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid0\leq\varphi\leq\pi,0\leq\theta\leq2\pi\}$. Since $$F^*x=\sin\varphi\cos\theta,\quad F^*y=\sin\varphi\sin\theta,\quad\text{and }\,\, F^*z=\cos\varphi,$$

What is meant by $F^\ast x$? Previously the definitions of pullbacks of linear maps and forms were introduced, but what exactly is this $F^\ast x$?

If the form being considered is $\frac{dy\wedge dz}{x}$, then

$$F^*\omega=\dfrac{F^* dy\wedge F^* dz}{F^*x}=\sin\varphi\,d\varphi\wedge d\theta.$$

Is it a property of pullbacks that $F^\ast(g\omega)=F^\ast(g) F^\ast \omega$? I didn't find this in the book. What if I had $\frac{dy\wedge dz}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}$?

Comment: What is your definition of pullback?

Comment: Isn't it just if $x = x(u,v,w)$, here $F^*x = x(F(\phi, \theta))$?

Answer (score 2):

$x,y$, and $z$ denote the three coordinates in $\mathbb R^3$. So, $F^*x$ means that you are pulling the first coordinate back to spherical coordinates; in other words, $F^*x = x(F(\phi,\theta))$ which outputs the first coordinate of $F$.

As for your question on $F^*(g\omega) = F^*(g)F^*(\omega)$. I am assuming that $g$ is a scalar function and $\omega$ is a $k$-form in $\mathbb R^3$; in this case, yes, the equation holds true.

As for the final concern, note that $F^*(d\omega) = d(F^*\omega)$, we have
$$\begin{split}F^*(\frac{dy\wedge dz}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}) &= F^*(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}})F^*(dy\wedge dz)\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(\sin\phi \cos\theta)^2 + \cos^2\phi}} F^*(dy\wedge dz)
\end{split}$$
Now, for $F^*(dy\wedge dz)$, one way to evaluate it is by pulling back each differential term then wedging the results as follows:
$$\begin{split}F^*(dy\wedge dz)&= F^*(dy)\wedge F^*(dz)\\
&= d(F^*y) \wedge d(F^*z)\\
&= d(\sin\phi\sin\theta) \wedge d(\cos\phi)\\
&= (\cos\phi\sin\theta \ d\phi + \sin\phi\cos\theta \ d\theta) \wedge (-\sin\phi \ d\phi)\\
&= -\cos\phi\sin\theta \sin\phi \ d\phi \wedge d\phi - \sin^2\phi\cos\theta \ d\theta \wedge d\phi\\
&= 0 + \sin^2\phi\cos\theta \ d\phi \wedge d\theta
\end{split}$$

We end up with 
$$F^*(\frac{dy\wedge dz}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}) = \frac{\sin^2\phi\cos\theta}{\sqrt{(\sin\phi \cos\theta)^2 + \cos^2\phi}}d\phi \wedge d\theta
 $$

Comment: I am assuming you're new to the realm of pullbacks of forms. Practicing with exercises is the only way to improve in finding them. I hope my example helped. Also, I believe you should have learned or will learn of a theorem that will assist greatly in finding $F^*(dy\wedge dz)$; I can't recall, but I'm sure there is one and I think here what you could do is find the determinant of the last two rows of $DF$ and multiply it with $d\phi \wedge d\theta$ to get the result.